# Update Case in Queue that User Should Not Have Access to in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, sharing, queue, case-sensitive

I'm using Email-to-case to generate cases from emails sent by internal employees. The case is automatically sent to a queue, ex: My Company's Inbox Queue. I only want specific users (designated by role) to be able to view the cases in this queue.

I have an auto response rule that sends back an "message received" email to the sender with a link to a flow that allows them to answer more detailed questions which are then written to fields on the case.

This works great for users who have access to the queue...

However, since the typical-end-user is not the owner of the case and is not shared the case in sharing rules because we don't want them to see it, the user cannot add additional information to the case from the flow because the flow is running at user level access.

In what ways can I address this so that users can update a case which they do not have access to in a flow? Is there any way I can force a flow to be ran in system mode? Or provide write, but not read/visibility access to this case and it's fields?

**Potential Workarounds:**

- Recreate the flow in a Visualforce Page or LWC, allowing the apex and
  updates to be ran in system mode.
- Use invocable methods in the flow to query and update the records in
  system mode.

Comment: Sounds like you already have a solution. Yes, Flows enforce sharing, so you can't bypass this restriction.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Yikes, you know you're really out of options when the fox says so. I got an architect big on flows due to ease of maintainability so I wanted to ensure I'm not overlooking some secret way to force this flow temporary system access or another "context" workaround, such as maybe putting the flow in a VFP with some special header etc.

Comment: Flow can write this data to a custom object. Process builder or autolaunched flow can then update the case.